# Оставить в String'е только буквы, цифры и пробелы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, replace

Какое надо использовать регулярное выражение replace, чтобы в строке остались только буквы, цифры и (!) пробелы.
Ну или по другому: удалить все символы из строки.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```java
String input = "\t!abc 1!!()абв~Ё";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("[^\\da-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ ]", ""));
```

`[^]` - выбирает любой символ который **НЕ** перечислен внутри квадратных скобок

Соответственно далее мы перечисляем что нам нужно оставить. А именно:

`\d` - Цифры

`a-zA-Z` - Английские символы

`а-яёА-ЯЁ` - Русские символы

(пробел) - он и в африке пробел

Comment: идеально! а самое главное - объяснили как именно пишутся эти выражения!)